# Twig: concatenate variable in string

Tags: twig

I've just begun learning Twig and i'm really stuck at this stupid little issue. Concatenating this doesn't seem to work (eigenKleurInput will ultimately be a  value):

```
{% set eigenKleurInput = "acefbf" %}
{% set customBackgroundColorInline = 'style=background-color: #' ~ eigenKleurInput %}
```

The output variable "customBackgroundColorInline" is put inside a div:

```
<section {{ customBackgroundColorInline }}>
```

Desired output would be

```
<section style="background-color: #xxx">
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question the problem is about encoded character: if you add the `"` in your code twig render as `&quot;`.

In this case you should use the [raw filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html) as follow:

```
{% set eigenKleurInput = "acefbf" %}
{% set customBackgroundColorInline = 'style="background-color: #' ~ eigenKleurInput ~ '"' %}


 <section {{ customBackgroundColorInline|raw }}>
```

So the output will be:

```
<section style="background-color: #acefbf">
```

You could try online in [this working twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/rymm40)

Hope this help